# Using StreamWriter: What is quicker writting one big string or many smaller pieces?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

I am generating an HTML output File in C#, though the speed performance for 60 Mb files seems to be impossibly long. It takes 20 minutes to generate the file, which is a very slow process. Previously around 35 Mb, it was generated in 5 Seconds, so I am not sure what is causing the delay here.

First I would be using these lines to start generating the report:

```
  public static void GenerateHtmlReport()
        {
            GenerateFinalResults();
            HtmlFileName ??= "Report-" + $"{DateTime.Now:dd_MMM_yyyy-[HH_mm]}" + ".html";
            var fileName = Path.Combine(GetRootFolder(), HtmlFileName);
            using var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
            using var w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8);
            w.WriteLine(RenderHtml.ContructReportHeader(User));
            RenderHtml.ConstructHtmlBody(Results, w);
            w.WriteLine(RenderHtml.ConstructFullSummaryReport(Results));
            w.WriteLine(RenderHtml.ContructDashboard(Results, ResultStart));
        }
```

If I am writing to the file full string, then it takes fairly long, nevertheless writing it piece by piece, isn't really much more helpful I see.

Though this leads me to two questions

1. Which process would be quicker, writing whole string or small pieces?
2. is there a different file writing method I should use to speed up the performance?

Regards,

Comment: Why don't you benchmark this? Although I doubt you'll notice any difference as StreamWriter uses an internal 1K buffer, and FileStream uses a 4K buffer by default. Both sizes can be changed

Comment: What do you mean by benchmark this?

Comment: It means actually measure the time taken in each case. If you need 20 minutes for 60MB  though, the problem has nothing to do with files. I'd guess the application uses inefficient string operations, creating lots of temporary strings that need to be garbage-collected. Even then going from 5 seconds to 20 minutes is a lot.

Comment: Instead of guessing, profile your application. In Visual Studio itself, you can check the [CPU and memory usage](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019) of the application while it's running. If you see ever-increasing memory usage, or a chainsaw image, the problem is indeed due to memory and garbage collection. Strings are immutable, so *any* string modification operation creates a *new* string that needs to be GC'd eventually. Adding lots of items to a List<T> without specifying a capacity also leads to reallocations

Comment: I suspect that if you rewrite your code so you can step over functions, you'll realize that the delay comes from `RenderHtml.ContructReportHeader(User)` ,`RenderHtml.ConstructFullSummaryReport(Results)` and  `RenderHtml.ContructDashboard(Results, ResultStart)`, not from `WriteLine`. If any of those methods generates anything more than a single *short* line, it should write the output directly to the writer instead of buffering 60MB of text in memory to write it out at the end

Comment: I would generating the strings as `mainString += "Then a long String"`, could this be the reason?

Comment: Yes. That's extremely inefficient. One solution is to use a StringBuilder, preferably with a `capacity` argument specifying a rough estimate of how many characters are expected. In this case though, where you want to write directly to a file, it's better to pass a `TextWriter` to the methods and have them write to it directly. Once you do that, if you really want a string in memory you can pass an instance of `StringWriter` instead of `StreamWriter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer indeed is the StringBuilder. Amending all parts of the code, instead of using + (concatenation) I sued StringBuilder.Append() and returned back it as a string. This is now creating the report in under 5 seconds instead of the 22 minutes. So it is a huge improvement.

Comment: Not really. There is no need to keep 60 MB of text in memory (in StringBuilder). Instead of `stringBuilder.Append` can be written directly to a stream using `streamWriter.Write`.

Comment: We would not keep it all in memory but by logical blocks and on the next iteration it would become again empty. Though. yes we could write all to the file instead, but this works for me.